# Excel Formula, Replace Current Text If Keyword in Another field, Otherwise, Don't Replace The Current Text

Tags: excel, conditional-statements

I need an excel formula that will check another field to see if a particular word is there.  If the word is there it will change the current field to something, but if the word is not there, it will leave the current field alone and not change it if it already has text in it.

I am using this formula, but it replaces the field with blank space instead of just leaving it alone.  I need it to NOT replace the current text with anything unless it finds a match.

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*credits*",G1)),"PayPal Customer","")
```

Thanks!

Craig

Comment: How does the cell get the value you want to leave untouched? If it's not coming from a formula then this approach isn't going to work: a cell can either contain a formula or not - you can't add a formula "conditionally".

Comment: Thanks for the comments all.  Answer below.  I should have considered that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Excel, a cell can contain either a value, or a formula.

To achieve the effect you want, place into G3

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*credits*",G1)),"PayPal Customer",G2)
```

Then, place the original value into G2 (possibly hiding the column to reduce clutter) and then  G3 will contain the required value.

Comment: Thanks Pekka.  I should have guessed that.  Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 0):

**1st :**
You don't need wildcard characters '*' in SEARCH, it will give wrong result as use of this will return 1 (first character) if SEARCH succeeds.

**2nd :**
You should use ***=ISERROR()*** and not *=ISNUMBER()* to check for error if search fails.

**3rd:**
Your answer is :)

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("CREDITS",G1)),"","Pay pal customer")
```